# how to make an outer shadow for a custom Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Is it possible to appear an outer shadow for my control when the mouse move over it? in winforms?

I can change its appearance, but a shadow?

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddEllipse(0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        this.Region = new Region(path);


        base.OnPaint(pevent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the asker. I can add another label behind the control, and make it appear as a shadow when mouse hover.